# Next.js Firebase - getDocs() only returning first document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security

I need the entire collection. Below, the `places` variable is only returning the first document. Thanks for the help.

```
import { app, auth } from '../firebase'
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs, getDoc, setDoc, where, query } from 'firebase/firestore'

  useEffect(() => {
    const getList = async () => {
      const places = query(collection(getFirestore(app), 'places'), where('UserID', '==', user.uid))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(places)
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const placeInfo = doc.data()
        setCurrentPlaces(currentPlaces !== undefined ? [...currentPlaces, placeInfo] : placeInfo)
      })
    }
    getList()
  }, [])
```

Please help with the given Firestore configs, not different ones.

Here are the Firestore database rules I am using:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /places/{PlaceID} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.UserID;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the general layout in Firestore (not using Realtime Database):

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us the places of a single user.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. What other details do you need?

Comment: I cannot see in your screenshot a field called `UserID` that holds a UID. Can you show us the correct one?

Comment: So I checked for typos like that, I edited it for the example, but you can see in the screenshot that I was using a different field for it.

Comment: The authentication works in my situation, but I only get the first document, not all 3. Possibly worth noting- it also happens to be the one I seeded that returns, but the two I added from the application are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the state for every document, create the array containing data of all documents and update state only once as shown below:

```
// empty array as initial value
const [currentPlaces, setCurrentPlaces] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getList = async () => {
    console.log('User ID', user.id)
    const places = query(collection(getFirestore(app), 'places'), where('UserID', '==', user.uid))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(places)
  
    console.log(`Fetched ${querySnapshot.size} documents`);

    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data })
    setCurrentPlaces(data);
  }
  getList()
}, [])
```

If `querySnapshot.size` logs 1, then check the data in your documents again if you do actually have 3 documents matching the query or not.

Comment: That's not the answer. But thanks for confirming that I am using getDocs() as expected. It is logging one document. There are three documents with the same UserID as the one document it does return. The ```query()``` method is not working.

Comment: @coder9833idls in that case, can you share screenshots of those 3 documents where we can see the `UserID` field? Do ensure there are no whitespaces in the value.

Comment: It's only an example, you're going to have to trust me on that and focus on why the query is only returning one document when all three have the same UserID field values.

Comment: @coder9833idls the query should return all 3. Do ensure the field is present at root of document and exactly `UserID` and not `UserId` or `userID`. Also it'll be best if you can `console.log("'user.uid'")`, share a screenshot along with those 3 documents where we can see the UserID field. Even a small typing mistake and cause such issues.

Comment: Does the root of the document change when a document is seeded from the Firestore console versus a document ```CREATE``` from an api call? Is there another key or nesting in JSON? That might be the difference.

Comment: @coder9833idls I meant the field is not nested like BuildingManager but on root level like values. Can you edit your questions and the screenshots? It might help to find the issue in shorter time.

Comment: If in an off chance this query is expected to work, does anybody know how I can contact Google Cloud Platform and bring it to their attention?

Comment: @coder9833idls you can contact the Google Cloud Platform team by using this link: https://cloud.google.com/contact